# Sum a list of integers inside a list dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a slight issue. I have a `model` class which has a list. Inside the list is another list which I need to implement a summation of integers. I keep getting this range error issue from my dart code when implemented with a for loop. Whats the cleanest way to achieve this summation?

**Main.dart**

```
 int totalSpendAmount = 0;
  int totalSpendQuantity = 0;
  List<int> spendList = [];
  List<int> quantityList = [];
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: widget.materials != null ? widget.materials.length : 0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          amountPlan = FlutterMoneyFormatter(
                  amount: (widget.materials[index].budget.toDouble()))
              .output;
          //for loop to calculate all purchases for amount and quantity spent
          for (var i = 0; i < widget.materials.length; i++) {
            if(widget.materials[index].purchase!=null){
           widget.materials.forEach((e) => totalSpendAmount += e.purchase[index].amount);
            }
            spendList.add(totalSpendAmount);
          }
```

**Model Class**

```
class Materials {
  String id;
  String title;
  String brand;
  String measurementUnit;
  int proposedQuantity;
  int budget;
  int quantityInStore;
  int quantityUsed;
  int unitCost;
  bool approved;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  String taskId;
  List<Purchase> purchase;

  Materials(
      {this.id,
        this.title,
        this.brand,
        this.measurementUnit,
        this.proposedQuantity,
        this.budget,
        this.quantityInStore,
        this.quantityUsed,
        this.unitCost,
        this.approved,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.taskId,
        this.purchase});
  static List<Materials> fromJsonList(List<dynamic> _list) {
    return _list.map((_tasks) => Materials.fromJson(_tasks)).toList();
  }

}

class Purchase {
  String id;
  int quantity;
  int amount;
  int discount;
  String receipt;
  String materialId;
  String projectId;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  String purchasedBy;

  Purchase(
      {this.id,
        this.quantity,
        this.amount,
        this.discount,
        this.receipt,
        this.materialId,
        this.projectId,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.purchasedBy});
  }
```

I need a list of all summation of `amount` integer inside the `Purchase` object for materials indexes which would be passed inside my `ListView.Builder's` widget

Comment: I'm just making sure. Here you mean for `(var i = 0; i < widget.materials.length; i++)` not `for (var i = 0; i < widget.materials.length + 1; i++)` right?

Comment: yeah. just trying to loop through the materials array so I could fetch the purchase object for each indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `fold` method. You can check this documentation
https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/fold.html

Comment: @bnotion thoughts check this gist https://gist.github.com/bagnaramon/99d6041a32125fb39db167946472edfd